# extract values from a result in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this script

```
api = ubidots.ApiClient('BBOO-b0c9e35928db729b1e6535be2eeee2e35956')
dt = client.get_datasource('5a1db98d180cae4297lld70f')
all_variables =  my_specific_datasource.get_variables()
for variables in all_variables:
         print (variables.name) + str(variables.get_values(1))
```

Which gives me the next line

```
rssi[{u'timestamp': 1520277036000, u'created_at': 1520277048408, u'value': -92.0, u'context': {}}]
```

The question is how do i take only the value of timestamp and value from the previous line, to upload it to a csv.

I'm not very expert in the subject, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is a dictionary. It appears you wish to filter your dictionary for specific keys. The pythonic way to achieve this is via a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {u'timestamp': 1520277036000, u'created_at': 1520277048408, u'value': -92.0, u'context': {}}

result = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in ('timestamp', 'value')}
```

`result` extracts only 2 keys from  your dictionary and outputs a dictionary containing only these 2 keys and their values.